# Use PHPStorm 6 LiveEdit on another machine

Tags: phpstorm, liveedit

I am using PHP Storm 6 on a Mac and was wondering if there is any way to use a Windows 7 based laptop next to it to preview my work via LiveEdit.

I have a Virtual Host configured on the Mac (as follows) and connect to it via http://somehost.dev -

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName somehost.dev
  DocumentRoot "/Users/benjaminmcmahan/PhpstormProjects/TEVFDDev/htdocs/"
  <Directory "/Users/benjaminmcmahan/PhpstormProjects/TEVFDDev/htdocs/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AddType text/shtml .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have the Chrome JetBrains IDE extension installed on the Mac and Live Edit works fine. I noticed that there is the option to set an IP address and port for the extension to use, which I would think means that it would be possible to listen for LiveEdit from another machine. The IP address of the Mac is 192.168.2 - using this IP address I am able to view `somehost.dev` on the Windows machine and set the Windows machine's JetBrains IDE IP to 192.168.1.2. However, LiveEdit does not do anything on this machine.

Is it possible to set up such a configuration?